# How to Save and Display user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am trying to get user input (debts), save to local storage, and display the user input to a div (results) for the results. When I hit the submit button nothing happens. What I would like it to do is push the debts input to the array and then post it to the results div.

HTML:

```
    <form id="myForm">
```

This is where the input starts, there are 3 different kinds; name, amount and due

```
    <!-- entering debt name -->
    <div class="name" id="name">
      <label>Debt Name: </label>
      <input type="text" class="debtname" id="debtname">
    </div>

    <!-- entering debt amount -->
    <div class="amount" id="amount">
      <label>Amount: </label>
      <input type="number" class="debtamount" id="debtamount">
    </div>

    <!-- entering debt due date -->
    <div class="due" id="due">
      <label>Due Date: </label>
      <input type="number" class="debtdue" id="debtdue" min="1" max="31">
    </div>      

    <!-- sumbitting debt information -->
    <input type="button" class="submitdebt" id="submitdebt" onclick="insert()" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

This is the div where I would like the results to be posted

```
    <!-- input results -->
    <div class="results" id="results"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', saveDebt);

// Save Debt
function saveDebt(e) {
   // Get form values
   var debtName = document.getElementById('debtname').value;
   var debtAmount = document.getElementById('debtamount').value;
   var debtDue = document.getElementById('debtdue').value;

   if(!validateForm(debtName, debtAmount, debtDue)) {
      return false;
   }
```

I want all the input to be put as an object that will be passed into an array

```
   var debtObject = {
     name: debtName,
     amount: debtAmount,
     due: debtDue
   }
```

This is where I think the main problem is, I don't think the input is being pushed into the array

```
   // Test if debts is null
   if(localStorage.getItem('debts') === null) {
      // Init array
      var debts = [];
      // Add to array
      debts.push(debtObject);
      // Set to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('debts', JSON.stringify(debts));
    } else {
      // Get debts from localStorage
      var debts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('debts'));
      // Add debt to array
      debts.push(debtObject);
      // Re-set back to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('debts', JSON.stringify(debts));
    }

// Clear form
document.getElementById('myForm').reset();

// Re-fetch debts
fetchDebts();

// Prevent form from submitting
e.preventDefault();
}
```

This is the function to print the results to the results div

```
// Fetch debts
function fetchDebts() {
   // Get debts from localStorage
   var debts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('debts'));
   // Get output id
   var results = document.getElementById('results');

   // Build output
   results.innerHTML = '';
   for( var i = 0; i < debts.length; i++) {
      var name = debts[i].name;
      var amount = debts[i].amount;
      var due = debts[i].due;

      results.innerHTML += '<div class="well">'+
                                            '<p>' + 'Name: ' + name +
                                            'Amount: ' + amount +
                                            'Due: ' + due +
                                            '</h3>'+
                                            '</div>';
     }
}

// Validate Form
function validateForm(debtName, debtAmount, debtDue) {
   if(!debtName || !debtAmount || !debtDue) {
      alert('Please fill in the form');
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
// modal end
```

Comment: This doesn't look to have anything to do with Java. Please try to figure out the name of the language you're trying to write code in, and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java. Please update your question. :-)

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/tmjsk75u/7/ =)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle to make it easier to debug your code here (and made fixes to it) - http://jsfiddle.net/9ra0dhtg/6/

I notice in your code you have :

```
<input type="button" class="submitdebt" id="submitdebt" onclick="insert()" value="Submit"/>
```

I assume you wanted to either call `saveDebt` here perhaps. If not, since you are trying to handle the form submit event, you should just create this as a form submit input (`type="submit"`) and remove the onclick handler and the rest of the flow would work as you intended it to.